# Are there some discussions about Buddhism in science?

Tags: reference-request, cognitive-science-of-religion

Buddhists are masters in observing what occurs on their minds, i.e what we call subjective as feelings, thoughts and more first-person stuff.

They really seem to understand how inmaterial world works (it might be obvious to some of you), but they lack of a materialist point of view. For example, they can study feelings occurring on their minds and modify it, but do not have a clear idea regarding the brain-basis of those feelings.

Are there any reviews or essays discussing Buddhists' knowledge and how science can complement it?

Comment: “… not have a clear idea regarding the brain-basis of those feelings.” For this, we shouldn’t forget the fact that Buddhism began about 2560 years ago, at which time science (including physics, neuroanatomy, and neurophysiology), as we know it, didn’t exist.

Comment: This is on topic, but possibly a bit broad? _"Are there any reviews or essays discussing buddhists' knowledge and how science can complement it?"_ Could you perhaps provide more indications on the potential nature of the 'complement' you are after? Would EEG measures of meditation be a suitable answer? Would comparing epistemological perspectives be a valid answer?

Comment: @StevenJeuris you're right but I really don't know where to start...

Comment: @user287279 that's exactly why they could have thought about a material basis, 2560 years to start with...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some resources:

- Wikipedia has a whole page for [Buddhism and science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism_and_science) in specific and [Cognitive science of religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_science_of_religion#Minimally_counterintuitive_concepts) in general.
- [Alan Wallace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B._Alan_Wallace)'s [Buddhism and Science](https://smile.amazon.com/Buddhism-Science-B-Alan-Wallace/dp/0231123353)
- Tricycle's [The Scientific Buddha](https://tricycle.org/magazine/scientific-buddha/). Tricycle is a Buddhism-oriented magazine that is quite popular
- [Mind and Life Institute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_and_Life_Institute). One of its founder is Dalai Lama, and it hosts [MindRxiv](https://mindrxiv.org/) preprint. You can find many preprints in the field there
- The [mindfulness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindfulness) technique is widely used in therapy

Answer (score 3):

Another relevant book is [*Why Buddhism is True: The Science and Philosophy of Meditation and Enlightenment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_Buddhism_Is_True) by the science journalist Robert Wright. The focus is on Vipassanā Buddhism, especially on meditation. His bibliography is extensive.